# Connect to phpmyadmin MySql on vps server vb net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, remote-access

I need connect to my MySQL database which is on my hosting in phpmyadmin.
I have one table with clients there and I want to connect there and later display table in my desktop app I'm trying to code.
The problem is that I can not even make a successful connection with my code, which seems to me ok as I saw many ppl use it, so I would appreciate some senior developer for his suggestion and help.

**PS:** *I tried to change domain name with IP of hosting account, I tried also check white-list of IP all ok*
My code:

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

    Public Class Form1
        Dim MySqlConn As MySqlConnection
        Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            MySqlConn = New MySqlConnection
            MySqlConn.ConnectionString =
                "server=mydomain.com; port=2083; userid=database_user; password=password; database=database_name"
            Try
                MySqlConn.Open()
                MessageBox.Show("Connection Successful!")
                MySqlConn.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            Finally
                MySqlConn.Dispose()
            End Try
        End Sub
    End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

So I dig more deeply and here is what I did :D

1. I was going to my VPS account I wanted enable the remote access of MySql.
2. in hosting cPanel I click on: Remote MySQL
3. then I simple enter in the field 'Remote Database Access Hosts' my IP by googling WhatismyIP and ALLOWED MY IP to remote connect.
4. I change my code I found on google (again) so here is working code:

   > Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
   >
   > ```
   > Public Class Form1
   >     Dim MysqlConn As MySqlConnection
   >     Dim ContactsCommand As New MySqlCommand
   >     Dim ContactsAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
   >     Dim ContactsData As New DataTable
   >     Dim SQL As String
   >
   >     Private Sub btnGrabData_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnGrabData.Click
   >         MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection()
   >
   >         ' Define the SQL to grab data from table.
   >         SQL = "SELECT * FROM clients"
   >
   >         'Connection String
   >         MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=mydomain.com;" _
   >         & "user id=user_of_databse;" _
   >         & "password=Database_pass;" _
   >         & "database=Database_name"
   >
   >         ' Try, Catch, Finally
   >         Try
   >             MysqlConn.Open()
   >
   >             ContactsCommand.Connection = MysqlConn
   >             ContactsCommand.CommandText = SQL
   >
   >             ContactsAdapter.SelectCommand = ContactsCommand
   >             ContactsAdapter.Fill(ContactsData)
   >
   >             DataGridView1.DataSource = ContactsData
   >
   >         Catch myerror As MySqlException
   >             MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to database: " & myerror.Message)
   >         Finally
   >             MysqlConn.Close()
   >             MysqlConn.Dispose()
   >         End Try
   >
   >     End Sub
   >
   > End Class
   > ```

Voila! THAT's IT!! I have now all clients from table name displayed in DataGridView :) First in mylife I answer myself on really hard thing hehe